Может ли дополнение иметь отношение к нескольким определениям перечисленным через запятую?
Вопрос касается термина из ПДД.
"Перекресток" - место пересечения, примыкания или разветвления дорог на одном уровне, ограниченное воображаемыми линиями, соединяющими соответственно противоположные, наиболее удаленные от центра перекрестка начала закруглений проезжих частей.
Можно ли считать что фраза "от центра перекрестка" имеет отношение к слову "противоположные"?  Или другими словами можно ли написать так:
"противоположные от центра перекрестка и наиболее удаленные от центра перекрестка"?
Если нет то о какой "противоположности" может идти речь?

Нет. Разберемся. Перекресток — место(какое?) место пересечения, примыкания или разветвления дорог на одном уровне, ограниченное воображаемыми линиями (какими?) соединяющими (что?) соответственно противоположные(какие?), наиболее удаленные от центра перекрестка начала закруглений проезжих частей.
Получается слово "противоположные" как и определение "наиболее удаленные от центра перекрестка" относится к фразе "начала закруглений проезжих частей".
Иными словами, противоположные начала закругленых проезжих частей, удаленных от центра перекрестка.

Спасибо! Вроде я все понял.

Если ваша проблема решена, то можно принять ответ, а также проголосовать за него (галочка и стрелка).
